# perl grep multiple pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to grep and match two patterns

`if(grep /mystatus eq 'PASSED\||FAILED/ && /myupdate ne TEST/, @try)`  then it should print "ok". However its not matching correctly. it prints 'not matching'. Could you please suggest ? Thanks in Advance.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(FILE,"myfile");
my @file = <FILE>;


if(grep /mystatus eq 'PASSED\||FAILED/ && /myupdate ne TEST/, @file)
{
print "ok";
}
else
{
print "not matching\n";
}
```

## myfile has these lines

## mystatus=PASSED

## myupdate=TESTED

Comment: Your script doesn't run! Please edit your question and give real script.

Comment: Hi Toto, please find the modified script. Thanks.

Comment: put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script then run it. Fix the reported errors.

Comment: That still does not compile `Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/mystatus=( <-- HERE PASSED\||FAILED/ at /home/john/test.pl line 6` Perl version 5.24.1

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. Please find the modified script. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Updated the whole thing correctly. Please verify. thanks

Comment: You can't grep two lines at the same time.

Comment: Try this: `if (   (grep /mystatus\s*=\s*(?:PASSED|FAILED)/, @file) &&  !(grep /myupdate\s*=\s*TEST/, @file) ) { ... }`

Comment: Please suggest any alternate way to match those two lines using those matching pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;


my $str = <DATA>;

if ( $str =~ /(?s)^(?=.*mystatus\s*=\s*(?:PASSED|FAILED))(?=.*myupdate\s*=\s*(?!TEST\b))/ ) {
    print "ok";
}
else {
    print "not matching\n";
}


__DATA__

mystatus=PASSED

myupdate=TESTED
```

Comment: Thanks Toto and Sin and Håkon Hægland for your help.

Comment: Honestly, I'd say regex really is the wrong tool for this particular job.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so no one's actually written about the actual problem with your code.

grep matches a condition. You're specifying `//` which means 'match a regex', and then you don't supply an actual regex.

Also you're escaping your `|` that's conditional, so you're matching a literal.

```
print "This matches\n" if "myupdate ne TEST" =~ /myupdate ne TEST/;
```

This isn't going to do what you want.

If you did want to do a `regex` test, you'd need something a little different, like this:

So for example:

```
while ( <DATA> ) {
   print "Matching line $_" if m/mystatus=(PASSED|FAILED)/;
}

__DATA__
mystatus=PASSED
myupdate=TESTED
```

The second problem is - you read your file into `@try` which splits based on lines. So both patterns will *never* match, because they're evaluated separately.

You can take several approaches to this, but one would be to set "$/" which is the record separator - set to `undef` and everything is read into a single  array element, but... then it gets a bit banal if you then slurp into an array.

So I'd urge you not to use `grep` for this task in the first place - `grep` is great for filtering a list of elements based on a condition, but that's not actually what you're trying to do.

So I'd suggest what you should actually do is not `grep` at all, and instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl; 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 

my %values = map { /(\w+)=(\w+)/ } <DATA>;


#for debug
print Dumper \%values;

print "OK\n" if $values{'mystatus'} eq 'PASSED' and $values{'myupdate'} eq 'TESTED'; 

__DATA__
mystatus=PASSED
myupdate=TESTED
```

This will use the `map` function to select key-value pairs out of your input file, and then just let you test the contents of a particular key, like you seem to want.

Or to use your more complicated logic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl; 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 

my %values = map { /(\w+)=(\w+)/ } <DATA>;


#for debug
print Dumper \%values;

print "OK\n" if ( $values{'mystatus'} eq 'PASSED' or $values{'mystatus'} eq 'FAILED' ) 
                   and $values{'myupdate'} eq 'TESTED'; 

__DATA__
mystatus=PASSED
myupdate=TESTED
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sobrique. I'll try this method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file;
{ 
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh, '<', 'path/to/file' or die "unable to open file: $!"
    $file = <$fh>;
}
if($file =~  /^(?=.*\bmystatus=(?:PASSED|FAILED)\b)(?=.*\bmyupdate=TESTED\b)/) {
    say "ok";
} else {
    say "not matching";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It prints `not matching` . but my input file contains matching lines which are  `mystatus=PASSED`
`myupdate=TESTED`